# It's not working that superview bring the subview to front. how to do it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I use many function to bring subview to superview but it is not working.
for example

```
[superview bringSubviewToFront:suberview];
[superview insertSubview:suberview belowSubview:someView];
[superview insertSubview:suberview aboveSubview:someView];
```

are not working

but `[superview sendSubviewToBack:suberview];`

it is working.

Comment: Made edit on your question and add complete method where you ar using this code.

Comment: setting suberview.layer.zPosition = MAXFLOAT; before inserting to superview also not working?

Comment: change color of View to BLACK or RED to make it visible, than check its position.

Comment: can't understand the portion `bring subview to superview` of your question. please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to explain you this. Suppose you are having a ViewController containing its own UIView. Then you have certain UIViews in it like view1, view2. view2 is infront of view1. you want to bring view1 infront of view2. All you need to do is call this method.

`[self.view bringSubviewToFront:view1];` 
self.view is parent view and view1 is the view in views hierarchy whom you want to bring in the front.

if you want to send view1 back. You can achieve this by using

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:view1];
```

it will send view1 to the back and view2 will be shown at the front.